# string comparision with a substring in php?

Tags: php, string

the string present in the array are `ATA Report of 7th Apr 2014, ATA Report of 17th Apr 2014, ATA Report of 27th Apr 2014`

I have the sub string `7th Apr 2014`

How can I find `ATA Report of 7th Apr 2014` position

I hav used like this but not worked for me

```
$date = "7th Apr 2014"
if (strpos("ATA Report of 7th Apr 2014", $date) !== false){
//my code.........

}
```

Comment: What do you mean "not worked for me" It should work just fine

Comment: @Simon_eQ, It won't work fine as the `strpos()` is not used properly.

Answer (score 1):

You need to loop them over..

```
<?php
$arr=array("ATA Report of 7th Apr 2014", "ATA Report of 17th Apr 2014", "ATA Report of 27th Apr 2014");
foreach($arr as $k=>$v)
{
    if(strpos($v,"7th Apr 2014") !== false)
    {
        echo "The position is $k";
        break;
    }
}
```

Also, the `strpos()` you are using it in a wrong way... the haystack should come first , followed by the needle.

Comment: @user3518270, That is what the code does. It returns the position 0 as `7th Apr 2014` is on the first position of the array.

Comment: @user3518270, I am sorry , I have modified the code. You are right.